# Change video playback speed of streaming videos, vb.net windows media player

Tags: vb.net, video, video-streaming, vimeo

I'm using this code to change the playback speed in windows media player (embedded in my form):

```
If (AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.isAvailable("Rate")) Then
           AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.rate = 0.5 '<-- insert you speed here as a double
            Label3.Text = "0.5x"
        End If
```

but, this is not working when I'm inserting a URL in the source of Windows Media Player.
i.e., it is working fine when  AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "E:\VIDEOS\FAV\count.mp4"
but when the URL is  AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "http://www.sdfsdf.com/ddsf.mp4", I'm not able to adjust the playback speed

Comment: use `player.settings.isAvailable("Rate")` to see if that playback rate is available with that format.

Comment: Yeah.. It's showing "True"